# Django! Dynamic url error

Tags: django

I'm trying make hyperlink to next page. But I get error.
Reverse for 'show_units_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
Please check my code.

view.py

```
def units_list(request):
    units_list = unit.objects.all()
    return render_to_response(
        'portal/units.html',
        {'units': units_list},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Main web portal entrance.
    (r'^$', views.portal_main_page),
    url(r'^portal/', views.units_list, name='show_units_list'),
)
```

html

```
<a href="?page={% url show_units_list %}">
```

Thanks

Comment: Is units_list part of an app? In which case it should be `{% url 'appname:urlname' %}`

Comment: In your urls you have:

    views.units_list

whereas in your html you have

    show_units_list

You are referring to a url that does not exist

Comment: Is your urls.py shown the primary urls.py for the site, or is it inside an app? If the latter, have you included it in your main urls.py?

Answer (score 0):

You forget **app_name**,

```
url(r'^portal/', app_name.views.units_list, name='show_units_list'),
```

Comment: Not if he imported views from app_name.

Comment: you can try, url(r'^portal/', portal.views.units_list, name='show_units_list'),

Comment: What is the folder name contains of the views.py ?

Comment: It's wrong filder name contains! If I delete folder name error don't fixing

Answer (score 0):

units_list is part an app "portal"

Comment: Thanks everyone! I fix all problems